# PHP nested menu with expand on click

Tags: php

I’am trying to create an nested PHP menu that should expand submenus on click, i can't use Javascript so everything need to be PHP. Right now i store my menu layout in an array:

```
Array
(
    [items] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 1
                [menu_name] => menu1
                [menu_parent] => 0
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 7
                [menu_name] => menu3
                [menu_parent] => 0
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 6
                [menu_name] => menu2
                [menu_parent] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 2
                [menu_name] => menu1-1
                [menu_parent] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 4
                [menu_name] => menu1-2
                [menu_parent] => 1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 5
                [menu_name] => menu1-3
                [menu_parent] => 1
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 17
                [menu_name] => menu1-4
                [menu_parent] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 3
                [menu_name] => menu1-1-1
                [menu_parent] => 2
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 18
                [menu_name] => menu1-1-1-1
                [menu_parent] => 3
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 20
                [menu_name] => menu7-2
                [menu_parent] => 11
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [menu_id] => 19
                [menu_name] => menu7-1
                [menu_parent] => 11
            )

    )

[parents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 7
                [2] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 5
                [3] => 17
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 18
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20
                [1] => 19
            )

    )

)
```

To loop the array and create the menu I use this function:

```
function buildMenu($parent, $menu)
{
   $html = "";
   if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent]))
   {
      $html .= "<ul>\n";
       foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
       {
          if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
            //IF MENU DONT HAVE SUBMENU
             $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='?c=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_id']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_name']."</a>\n</li> \n";
          }
          if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             //IF MENU HAS SUBMENU
             $html .= "<li>\n <a href='?c=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_id']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_name']."</a> \n";      
             $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu);
             $html .= "</li> \n";
          }
       }
       $html .= "</ul> \n";
   }
   return $html;
}
echo buildMenu(0, $menu);
```

That function will generate the whole menu and show all submenus directly:

```
menu1 (?c=1)
   menu1-1 (?c=2)
      menu1-1-1 (?c=3)
         menu1-1-1-1 (?c=18)
   menu1-2 (?c=4)
   menu1-3 (?c=5)
   menu1-4 (?c=17)
menu3 (?c=7)
menu2 (?c=6)
```

I wonder if their is an easy way to modify my function to only display the selected submenus?
Exempel: menu.php?c=1_2

```
menu1 (?c=1)
   menu1-1 (?c=1_2)
      menu1-1-1 (?c=1_2_18)
   menu1-2 (?c=1_4)
   menu1-3 (?c=1_5)
   menu1-4 (?c=1_17)
menu3 (?c=7)
menu2 (?c=6)
```

Comment: "I’am trying to create an nested PHP menu that should expand submenus on click, i can't use Javascript so everything need to be PHP." - You realize then the page will reload every time you click? Why can't you use JavaScript?

Comment: Since you can't use javascript have you considered looking into pure CSS drop down menus, save the page refresh each click. Not sure on browser support though.

Comment: Also what type of site is this being used for?

Comment: Fredd, thanks for you answer. I have considered CSS drop down menus, but i want to avoid hover menus right now...

Answer (score 0):

Use an array for checking if the node of the menu is selected, in that case continue with the recursion, if the node is not selected or does not have submenu then return from the recursion

```
function buildMenu($parent, $menu, array $selection)
{
   $html = "";
   if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent]))
   {
      $html .= "<ul>\n";
       foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
       {
          if(!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
            //IF MENU DONT HAVE SUBMENU
             $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='?c=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_id']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_name']."</a>\n</li> \n";
          }

          if(!in_array($menu['parents'][$itemId], $selection)) 
          {
            //IF MENU OPTION IS NOT SELECTED DON'T SHOW SUBMENU
             $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='?c=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_id']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_name']."</a>\n</li> \n";
          }

          if(isset($menu['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             //IF MENU HAS SUBMENU
             $html .= "<li>\n <a href='?c=".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_id']."'>".$menu['items'][$itemId]['menu_name']."</a> \n";      
             $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menu, $selection);
             $html .= "</li> \n";
          }
       }
       $html .= "</ul> \n";
   }
   return $html;
}
```

For example, if item 18 is selected you should call the function like (with all the selected items in the array):

```
$selection = array(1, 2, 18);
buildMenu($parent, $menu, $selection);
```

This is just a quick approach (not even tested), you can refine much more the solution, but just giving an idea how to change the recursion of your function to achieve what you're looking for. You could include the second if into the first one just adding the condition to the first if (but more clear the way i wrote).

Hope this helps.